# What is ServiceMax in Salesforce? What is the need for it?

Tags: servicemax

I am newbie to "ServiceMax" in Salesforce. I want to learn about ServiceMax and Field service management(FSM) in Salesforce, how and why to use these in salesforce. There is no proper documentation around it. How can i use the ServiceMax in Salesforce org.

Can any one explain me briefly about "What is ServiceMax in salesforce and what is the use of it?". How can i work with 'ServiceMax' in developer org.

Answer (score 0):

ServiceMax is a company who builded a solution on top of the Salesforce platform to do field service. ServiceMax is a paying solution but is really strong in work order management and workforce management. ServiceMax allows you to schedule your field service engineers with work orders based on proximity, availability and skills. ServiceMax has also a mobile client which can be used for engineers to get their work orders signed on the location where they need to be.

It is a very complete solution for field service.